# What is the mistake here in this C# code?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Repeating2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] tal = new tal[3];
            int tal2 = { 2, 6, 5, 2, 35 };
            string str = { "hej", "på", "dig" };
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any wrong with this code ?

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'tal[]' to 'int[]'   Repeating2
> Error CS0118  'tal' is a variable but is used like a type Repeating2
> Error CS0622  Can only use array initializer expressions to assign to array types

Comment: The compiler already gave you the answer to your final question, yes there are things wrong with your code. The error messages tells you what is wrong.  Start by taking the first error message, then google it, and then check your code. What was the purpose of the statement that had this error?

Comment: Well, the error messages look quite clear to me. I would suggest focusing on the first one to start with. You've used `new tal[3]` as an array initializer... what do you expect that to do, and how do you expect to assign that to an `int[]` variable?

Comment: `tal2` and `str` need to be an arrays and your first line needs to be initialized as an int[] not a tal[]

Comment: There is no type called `tal` to be found by the compiler in any of the namespaces you have imported unless you have your own class/type called `tal`. You probably mean `int[] tal = new int[3]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Correct expressions** are like this

```
int[] tal = new int[3]; // new required data type (tal isn't)
int[] tal2 = { 2, 6, 5, 2, 35 }; // you are initializing int[]
string[] str = { "hej", "på", "dig" }; //you are initializing string[]
```

Comment: You should add explanations. How did you manage to be able to post an answer to a closed question? 

Comment: thx a lot guys, I am totaly new, and the people round me the suggest to ask here always and I surprised how much fast people want to Help !!!
Thx again I really appreciate